# Expose C++ object to Javascript in Qt

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebkit

Is there any way I can expose a C++ object/function to JavaScript running inside the QtWebKit browser in Qt? It's possible to expose ActionScript objects to JS code running inside the WebKit browser in Adobe AIR - I'm looking for similar functionality in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Take a look at [this.](https://blogs.kde.org/node/4008)  It should be a good start.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: LINK IS WORKING, BUT JUST IN CASE THE LINK BREAKS AGAIN [[Link]](http://blogs.kde.org/node/4008) by Richard Moore
...

> One question I've seen come up several times on #qt and qt-interest is how to
>   add custom (application specific) APIs to those available by default in
>   QtWebKit. This is actually pretty easy (once you know how) as I'll show
>   below. This post will show a simple example of how to make an object available
>   from javascript, including calling methods on the object and returning values
>   from C++.
>
> There are two things you really need to know in order to perform this
>   integration, the first is the addToJavaScriptWindowObject() method of
>   QWebFrame, this allows will make the specified QObject visible from
>   javascript. The second thing you need to know is that objects published in
>   this way will vanish each time the javascript window object is cleared -
>   ie. every time the user navigates to a new page. To prevent this from causing
>   problems, QWebFrame provides a signal that tells you whenever the object is
>   cleared allowing you to re-add your custom API. This is actually much simpler
>   than it sounds!
>
> The core of this is really implemented in two methods in the example, they're
>   shown below:

```
void MyApi::setWebView( QWebView *view )
{
    QWebPage *page = view->page();
    frame = page->mainFrame();

    attachObject();
    connect( frame, SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(attachObject()) );
}

void MyApi::attachObject()
{
    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( QString("MyApi"), this );
}
```

> This code is all that you need in order to make all of the public slots of the
>   MyApi object visible to javascript. The MyApi class provides two public slots:

```
public slots:
    void doSomething( const QString &param );
    int doSums( int a, int b );
```

> The first slot simply logs a message to the debug output, the second returns
>   the sum of its two arguments (yes, slots can return things!). They're called
>   from javascript like this:

```
  MyApi.doSomething( 'Hello from JS page 2!!!!' );

  sum = MyApi.doSums( 2, 3 );
  alert( 'C++ says the sum is ' + sum );
```

> And that's all there is to it! You can download the code from >http://xmelegance.org/devel/qtwebkitextension.tar.gz.

Comment: This example is not functional in QT5 unfortunately. Any chance for an update or shall I open another question?