# Expose C++ object to Javascript in Qt with QtWebEngine

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

With QtWebkit it is possible to expose C++ objects to Javascript via `QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20685002/595937

Can the same thing be accomplished in Qt 5.4 using QtWebEngine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exporting C++ objects to HTML/JS is not directly possible with QWebEngine.

Instead, the newly introduced **QWebChannel** provides a bridge between HTML/JS and C++. Have a look at [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html), especially at the examples. There was also a quite good introductory talk about QWebChannel at this year's Qt Developer Days, which might also be of interest to you. The videos of the talks will go online in a few weeks.

Comment: @ThomasMcGuire The link provided in your text is probably rotten. I believe this is the current working: [`QWebChannel` (Qt5)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html).

Comment: @Scheff: Thanks for notifying me about the broken URL, I've updated it now.